# Azure queue storage receiving duplicate messages

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I have added the code to redirect generated messages to azure queue. The queue receives multiple duplicate messages within a 1 minute timestamp, while in logs it prints "Attempt to send the message failed!". As you can see in the code there is a current sms provider that functions correctly so the function sendSMS seems to be executed only once.
Any idea why this could happen?

```
     private boolean sendSMS(String recipientId, String dispatchMessage) {

        Properties prop=null;
        try {
           prop=getSMSGatewayProperties("SMSGateway.properties");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"SMSGateway.properties",e);
            return false;
        }

        String token=prop.getProperty("key");   
        String storageConnectionString=prop.getProperty("conn");    
        String queueName=prop.getProperty("queue"); 
        String jsonString = new JSONObject()
                  .put("recipient",recipientId)
                  .put("message",dispatchMessage).toString();
        
        System.out.println("Connection with key to be established!");
        AMPClient client = new AMPClient(token); 
        System.out.println("Connection with key was established successfully!");
        try {
          // Send an SMS to one mobile number.
          System.out.println("Trying to send the message!");
          client.sendSMS(recipientId, dispatchMessage);
          System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
        } catch (APIException ex) {
            
            System.out.println("Attempt to send the message failed!");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        try
    {
    
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount =
           CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        System.out.println("Storage account retrieved!");
        
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.createCloudQueueClient();
        System.out.println("Client queue created!");
       
     
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference(queueName);
        System.out.println("Client queue reference retrieved!");
     
        queue.createIfNotExists();
        System.out.println("PW: Queue created!");

        CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(jsonString);
        System.out.println("Message created!");
        
        queue.addMessage(message);
        System.out.println("Message successfully sent to azure queue storage!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         System.out.println("Failed to send message to azure queue storage!");

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        
       
      }
        
        return true;}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting duplicate messages from Azure Storage Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556185/getting-duplicate-messages-from-azure-storage-queue)

Answer (score 0):

1. For Azure storage queue automatic duplicate detection is not
   supported. i.e. there is no mechanism to query Storage queue  if a
   message is duplicate. You can try to use azure service Bus which is
   something like Azure Storage Queue but can makes duplicate detection
   which is useful in cases of this error.
   ***[Compare Azure Queues and Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted#advanced-capabilities)***
2. There are some github discussions like [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2796#issuecomment-387916856) in case of azure
   functions queue trigger  duplicate meesages to use SingletonMode .
   Also check this [Add Singleton support for Functions to ensure only
   one function running at a time](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912#issuecomment-1059120967)